# TYPO3 v11 - how access the session id?

Tags: session, typo3, typo3-11.x

I'm updating a custom TYPO3 plugin from TYPO3 v10 to v11.

When a new user arrives, a record is set in the fe_sessions table, so clearly a new session is being created.  In TYPO3 v10, even if the user us not logged in, I could access that session id via:

```
$sessionId = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user['ses_id'];
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to do this in v11 please? I've not found anything in the documentation or web searches that quite fits the bill. The TYPO3\CMS\Core\Session\UserSessionManager looks promising, but you need to create a new userSession object with the userSessionManager to be able to access the sessionId. However all of the userSessionManager methods bar one to create the UserSession object require the session id as a parameter (circular trap). The only method that doesn't ask for a sessionId create a new anonymous session, which doesn't match the id in the fe_sessions table.

And since I want to access the sessionId on one page and re-access it on another as part of security check, any method that creates a new sessionId in order to view it won't work.

What am I missing?  Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this in v11, but in v12 you can do:

```
$sessionId = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->getSession()->getIdentifier();
```

With `getSession()` you will receive an instance of `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Session\UserSession`, which has the method `getIdentifier()` to retrieve the session id.

Comment: We've tried that, but the returning string is longer than the session-id hash from `fe_sessions` table: for example `d52f34a4b8aa196883a18d2cfac585da.1883b6b2a044bfde017c0d5d1e2f72f6c88051a0918f8f9ed3458aede964de43` is returned by `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->getSession()->getIdentifier()`. The part after the dot seems to be the `ses_id`, but it is not (at least there are no matches if I try to find a record by SQL query). Can someone explain this please? (PS: using TYPO3 11.5.33)

Comment: This hash with dot is created by `UserSessionManager::createSessionId()` (first-part is random, last-part is a HMAC signature). So the question remains: is there a way to get the pure session-id like it is in the database?

Comment: Yes, the session-id you get via `getIdentifier()` is not identical with the `ses_id` value in `fe_sessions`. But why is this important? I leave the handling of records in `fe_sessions` to the TYPO3 core. If you want to track different user sessions in your application (as OP mentions: "I want to access the sessionId on one page and re-access it on another as part of security check"), you only need a unique id to identify different users and that's what you get with the `getIdentifier()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The user information has been moved in TYPO3 v11 to the context and can be accessed with `$context->getPropertyFromAspect('frontend.user', '...');`

see the [manual](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/Context/Index.html#user-aspect)

Sessions have an own [UserSessionMangager](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/SessionStorageFramework/UserSessionManagement.html#public-api-of-usersessionmanager) and [API](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/SessionStorageFramework/UserSessionManagement.html#public-api-of-usersession)

Comment: Hi Bernd, many thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, the allowed parameters for getPropertyFromAspect do not include the sessionId. And the UserSessionManager has the circular trap issue I mentioned in my question. I don't see how to get the sessionId from either of these sources. Am I missing something?

Comment: I admit I haven't worked with user sessions and expected that the session would be initialized by TYPO3 core. Maybe there is a session manager already active? on the other hand there is a table field `fe_sessions.sys_userid` which probably hold the user-id. (if you need to query this field I would add an index to it)